# no-kafka consume produce problems

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka

Im using 'no-kafka' npm package (for nodejs),
I have 2 problems:

1. my app start by sending message to a topic that does not exist,
   my Kafka options set to "auto create topic" but when I send data to kafka its not create the topic.

   - if I use kafka producer (from console) it create topic, so problem is not in kafka
2. if I consume topic that not exist, no-kafka stop working ( I expect it to listen to this topic even if it not exist, and when topic created and data arrived everithing will work (like it work in the kafka console)

can you help me with those issues please?

Thanks,
Larry

Comment: problem still exist, does someone share same problem? or someone have a solution?

Comment: update 'no-kafka' version solved it, but now reconnect not work now :(